# Selecting from the spinner and clicking a button to open a new activity

Tags: android

Selecting from the spinner and clicking a button to open a new activity. Also, need a button back to default. can anyone help write a SecondActivity too?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// References to GUI components.
private Spinner cmbfruits;
private ImageView imgFruit;

// fruits names
private final String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Grapes", "Mango", "Pineapple", "strawberry"};
//  image fruit
// Both names and image fruit are in the same order
private final int[] fruitIDs = {R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.grapes, R.drawable.mango, R.drawable.pineapple, R.drawable.strawberry};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the GUI components.
    this.cmbfruits = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbfruits);
    this.imgFruit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFruit);

    // Create an array adapter and set it to the Spinner.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fruits);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    this.cmbfruits.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set the message to default.
    this.cmbfruits.setSelection(0);

    // Set itm selected listener.
    this.cmbfruits.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            imgFruit.setImageResource(fruitIDs[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What's the issue in this?

Answer (score 1):

For opening new activity set OnClickListener on button you want and use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityYouWantToOpen.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

More here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: can you write it clearly? I don't know where to put it

Comment: You want to start new activity on click on what? imgFruit?

Comment: I want an intent class that can make my spinner back to default.  And can you make the spinner start with the " choose an item" show in it?